# Не подгружается верстка, проблемы с маршрутизацией

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap, frontend

Имеем вот такую страницу:

```
import React from 'react';

const Shop = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      SHOP
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shop;
```

хочется увидеть ее вывод, для этого в файл приложения импортировал роутер приложения:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRouter from './components/AppRouter';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppRouter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Собственно сам файл AppRouter:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
import {authRoutes, publicRoutes} from "../routes";

const AppRouter = () => {
    const isAuth = false //временная авторицазия

    return (
        <Routes>
            {isAuth && authRoutes.map(({path, Component}) =>
                    <Route key={path} path={path} component={Component} exact/>
            )}
            {publicRoutes.map(({path, Component}) =>
                    <Route key={path} path={path} component={Component} exact/>
                )}
        </Routes>
    );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

Файл с маршрутами (routes):

```
import Admin from "./pages/Admin";
import {ADMIN_ROUTE, BASKET_ROUTE, DEVICE_ROUTE, LOGIN_ROUTE, REGISTRATION_ROUTE, SHOP_ROUTE} from "./utils/consts";
import Basket from "./pages/Basket";
import Shop from "./pages/Shop";
import Auth from "./pages/Auth";
import DevicePage from "./pages/DevicePage";

export const authRoutes = [
    {
        path: ADMIN_ROUTE,
        Component: Admin
    },
    {
        path: BASKET_ROUTE,
        Component: Basket
    },
]

export const publicRoutes = [
    {
        path: SHOP_ROUTE,
        Component: Shop
    },
    {
        path: LOGIN_ROUTE,
        Component: Auth
    },
    {
        path: REGISTRATION_ROUTE,
        Component: Auth
    },
    {
        path: DEVICE_ROUTE + '/:id',
        Component: DevicePage
    },
]
```

Слово SHOP так и не выводится. Подумал что что-то не так в самой верстке, ибо в консоли выдает ошибки по подключенным стилям, но нет, в отладчике слова SHOP тоже нет.

Что тут не так?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена:

```
<Routes>
        {isAuth && authRoutes.map(({path, Component}) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} exact/>
        )}
        {publicRoutes.map(({path, Component}) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} exact/>
            )}
    </Routes>
```